# How to change commutativity of a SymPy symbol after creation?

Tags: sympy

Suppose I create a SymPy symbol `x`.

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x', commutative = False)
```

How can I change the commutative assumption to `True` without creating a new Symbol?
I tried

```
with sp.assuming( sp.Q.commutative(x) ):
    print( sp.ask( Q.commutative(x) ) )
```

But it still gives `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy objects are immutable, so this isn't possible. Furthermore `commutative` is not supported by the new assumptions system (`ask`, `Q`, `assuming`).

What you should do instead is create a new symbol and use `subs` to replace it in whatever expression you want to make it commutative in.