# Make all symbols commutative in a sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy, commutativity

Say you have a number of non commutative symbols within a sympy expression, something like

```
a, c = sympy.symbols('a c', commutative=False)
b = sympy.Symbol('b')
expr = a * c + b * c
```

What is the preferred way to make all symbols in the expression commutative, so that, for example, `sympy.simplify(allcommutative(expr)) = c * (a + b)`?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760281/4063051) it is stated that there is no way to change the commutativity of a symbol after creation without replacing a symbol, but maybe there is an easy way to change in blocks all symbols of an expression like this?

Comment: Why were they created as noncommutative if they're supposed to be commutative?

Comment: @user2357112 legit question of course. My reason is that I want to force a specific ordering in the printed expression, and setting the symbols as non commutative was the easiest way I found to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `Eq(expr, c * (a + b))` to evaluate to True, you'll need to replace symbols by other symbols that commute. For example:

```
replacements = {s: sympy.Dummy(s.name) for s in expr.free_symbols}
sympy.Eq(expr, c * (a + b)).xreplace(replacements).simplify()
```

This returns True.

Comment: this is the kind of this I was thinking of, yes. I guess there is no better way then. Thanks

Comment: @glS Yeah, I wish I could make `x` commutative by saying `x.is_commutative=True`, but I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: Why doesn't calling `a, c = sympy.symbols('a c', commutative=False)` later work? It seems expressions involving those symbols are set in stone (as `subs` doesn't work on them).

Comment: @Geremia Sympy objects are immutable. Check out the "common pitfalls" section of the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Two comments:

1. noncommutatives will factor (though they respect the side that the nc expr appears on)
2. although you have a robust answer, a simple answer that will often be good enough is to just sympify the string version of the expression

Both are shown below:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> a, c = sympy.symbols('a c', commutative=False)
>>> b = sympy.Symbol('b')
>>> expr = a * c + b * c
>>> factor(expr)
(b + a)*c
>>> S(str(_))
c*(a + b)
```